# different types of storage specifiers in c?

Tags: c

what are different types of storage specifiers in c language?

Answer (score 8):

Formally there's no such thing as "storage specifier" in C. C has *storage-class specifiers*. There are five of them: `typedef`, `extern`, `static`, `auto` and `register`. Obviously, what `typedef` does is not exactly what is commonly understood under "storage class", but the concept of *storage-class specifier* in C has strong syntactic roots, which is why `typedef` was also included into that category.

Comment: NB there are now six, `_Thread_local` was added after this answer was written.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ash6ess9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) says :

- auto
- register
- static
- extern

I would add to that `volatile`.
I don't think `const` quite counts... but is similar.

If you include C++, more come into play, including `mutable`.

Comment: Hmm, viewing MSDN as a source of information about the C language. That could provoke some discussion....... Not that I'm saying you are wrong mind you!!

Comment: these are called storage classes.i am asking about storage specifiers

Comment: @David: I think more to the point, I'm viewing Google as a source of info.  And Google led me to MSDN.  I think the poster should have googled it.

Comment: @user615929: If you're going to argue terminology, the least you could do is provide a single example of what you mean.

Comment: @user:  Please specify what you are talking about then.  Can you name one or two specifiers as an example?

Comment: @user615929 I think they are actually called Storage Class Specifiers. Which ought to confuse the matter a little more.

Comment: `volatile` is the same as `const` (and C99 `restrict`) - it is a type qualifier. The C99 standard also lists `typedef` as a storage class specifier but only for syntactic convenience.